# From pandas dataframe to excel with xlwings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlwings

I have a pandas dataframe where I did a 24x 12 matrix with colors to be able to represent my data better.

[image]

What I want to do is put this in excel with xlwings. But I don't know how. I have already used xlwings with matplotlib and other graphical tools but I am stuck with this one.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book()
```

Ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use `df.style.apply(...).to_excel()`?

Answer (score 5):

You can paste the dataframe to xlwings to a specified range. See the following test example.

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([pd._testing.rands_array(5, 3),
                  pd._testing.rands_array(5, 3),
                  pd._testing.rands_array(5, 3),
                  ])

wb = xw.Book("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

ws["A1"].options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=True, expand='table').value = df

# If formatting of column names and index is needed as xlsxwriter does it, the following lines will do it.
ws["A1"].expand("right").api.Font.Bold = True
ws["A1"].expand("down").api.Font.Bold = True
ws["A1"].expand("right").api.Borders.Weight = 2
ws["A1"].expand("down").api.Borders.Weight = 2

wb.save(filename)
app.quit()
```

Comment: It looks like this doesn't work with `NA`s.

Comment: I guess you provided this on Github, it's supported since [version 0.27.11](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/whatsnew.html#v0-27-11-jul-6-2022).