# Python: How to save excel workbook without ruining dynamic spill/array formulas

Tags: python, excel

**Short description of the problem:**

I am currently accessing an Excel workbook from Python with openpyxl.
I have some dynamic spill formulas in sheet1, like filter(), byrow() and unique().
With the python script, I am doing some operations in sheet2, but I am not touching sheet1 (where the dynamic spill formulas are located).
When using workbook.save() method in Python, I experience that the dynamic formulas in sheet1 are ruined and static, not having the dynamic functionality they had before interacting with python.

*What can I do? Use a parameter in .save()? Use another method?*

**Detailed description of problem** (with pictures)**:**

I have a workbook called **Original**, with the following three sheets:

- nums
- dynamic
- dump

In "nums" I have a cell for ID (AA), and a column with some numerical values ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj7YY.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj7YY.png)).
In "dynamic" I have some dynamic formulas like byrow() and filter() that updates automatically with the values in ID and Values-column of "nums" ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvYzx.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvYzx.png)).
The sheet "dump" is for now empty.

I have a second workbook called **Some_data**, which have one sheet with a 3-column dataframe ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hEix.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hEix.png)).

I am dumping the 3-column dataframe of **Some_data** into the empty "dump"-sheet of **Original** with a Python script, and then using the workbook.save() method to save the new workbook.

The code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook


Some_data = filepath of the workbook
Original = filepath of the workbook

df = pd.read_excel(Some_data, engine = "openpyxl")

wb = load_workbook(filename = Original)
ws = wb["dump"]

rownr = 2
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ws["B"+str(rownr)] = row["col1"]
    ws["C"+str(rownr)] = row["col2"]
    ws["D"+str(rownr)] = row["col3"]
    rownr+=1
    
wb.save(filepath of new workbook)
```

Now, the newly saved workbook's sheet "dump" has now been populated.
**The problem is** that the dynamic formulas in the sheet "dynamic" has been ruined, although the python script does not interact with any of the sheets "nums" or "dynamic".
First of all - the dynamic array formulas (like filter) now have brackets around them ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0hJu.png)[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0hJu.png)), and the dynamic array formulas are not dynamic anymore (there are no blue line around the array when selected, and they do not update automatically; [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzs7n.png)[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzs7n.png)).

*I need help with what to do. I want to save the excel-file, but with the dynamic array formulas not being ruined.*

Thank you for your help, in advance.

Frode

Comment: I'm not sure how robust openpyxl's support is for Dynamic Array formulas. Other alternatives may be xlsxwriter, xlwings, or win32com.

Comment: @BigBen Thx for your comment. Would I be able to both read and save excel-files with one of those packages you just mentioned?

Comment: Yes, that is doable.

Comment: @BigBen Do you recommend one of them, that you know would tackle the dynamic formula issue?

Comment: `xlwings` or `win32com`  would generally require Excel to be installed on the machine. If that's an issue, than I'd try `xlsxwriter`.

Comment: As xlwings .Book() does not have a method called iterrows() - do you have any suggestions on how I solve the populating in the for-loop provided in the code?

Comment: `iterrows` is a pandas method.

Comment: I see @BigBen. Does xlwings have method that can replace the pandas iterrows()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65349008/from-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-with-xlwings

Comment: @BigBen, thank you. One question however: When using xlwings and workbook.save(filepath) - I get an error when there is a file in that directory that already has the same name. I want to overwrite though. Do you have an idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426763/xlwings-save-and-close ?

Comment: Thank you, but the solution there was entering the full filepath inside .save(). I am already doing that, but still receiving the error.

Comment: `save` should overwrite w/o prompt. If you're getting an error, likely that file is in use by another process. Btw, [the docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Book.save).

Comment: @BigBen, hi again. Thank you so much for your help. I have one last question/error if you should have the time. It is in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73864007/error-with-xlwings-book-save-saveas-method-of-workbook-class-failed

Comment: This question still doesn't have an answer, I believe